# why does break does not work inside the if else?

Tags: r

```
install.packages("dplyr") 
library(dplyr)
install.packages("magrittr")
library(magrittr)

patientsID<-unique(PATIENT$PatientID)
PATIENT$DOD<-as.Date(PATIENT$DOD)
patient_diag_dict<-list()
for (patient_id in patientsID) {
patientDiagnosisDF <- PATIENT %>%
filter(PatientID==patient_id)

chron_date <- patientDiagnosisDF$DOD
chron_ID <- patientDiagnosisDF$DID
patient_data <- data.frame('date' = chron_date,'id' = chron_ID)
patient_data <- patient_data[order(patient_data$date),]

patient_diag_dict[[toString(patient_id)]] <- patient_data

print(patient_diag_dict)
}

diagID<-c()

for(row in 1:nrow(ADMISSION)) {
print(row)
admis_row<-ADMISSION[row,]

patient<-admis_row$PatientID

proc_date<-as.Date(admis_row$PROCEDUREDATE)

if(!(toString(patient) %in% patient_diag_dict)) {
diagID <- c(diagID, NULL)
}

all_diag_date<-patient_diag_dict[[toString(patient)]]$date
all_diag_ids<-patient_diag_dict[[toString(patient)]]$id

mostRecentDiagID<-all_diag_ids[1]
for(i in 1:length(all_diag_date)) {
diag_date<-all_diag_date[i]
diag_id<-all_diag_ids[i]

if(proc_date >= diag_date) {
   mostRecentDiagID<-diag_id
} else {
  break
}
}

diagID <- c(diagID, mostRecentDiagID)

}

ADMISSION$DID<-diagID
```

I am trying to get the diagnosis date from the first data frame and the proc_date from the second data frame and trying to compare them. If procedure date is >= procedure date keep that record. If not break. But this break does not work inside the for loop.
The two data frames are listed below.

PATIENT dataframe

```
PatientID   DOD PRIMARYSITE
27  23-10-08    TRUNK
350 12-10-09    TRUNK
350 05-07-10    NECK
663 31-07-09    UPPERLIMB
663 25-02-09    TRUNK
663 24-06-09    TRUNK
585 03-10-11    HIP
736 30-01-13    OTHER
```

ADMISSION dataframe

```
PatientID   PROCEDUREDATE   ICD
27          25-09-13    SEDATION
27          25-09-13    LARGE BURSA
27          25-09-13    GENERAL ANESTHIA
27          18-06-04    SEDATION
27          16-07-04    LYMPHGROIN
27          31-08-04    GROIN
27          28-09-04    SEDATION
27          18-06-04    BIOPSY
663         20-04-10    DIETICS
663         10-02-09    SEDATION
663         15-03-11    EYELID
663         09-04-10    PHYSIOTHERAPY
663         20-08-09    BIOPSY
663         09-07-12    SEDATION
585         10-03-10    ANAESESIA
585         10-11-11    BIOPSY
585         08-09-13    SEDATION
585         12-04-08    DIETICS
736         02-05-09    CHEMO
736         09-07-14    BIOPSY
736         10-08-13    SEDATION
```

I am getting a dataframe 
ADMISSION dataframe

```
PatientID   PROCEDUREDATE   ICD             DID
27          25-09-13    SEDATION             2
27          25-09-13    LARGE BURSA          2
27          25-09-13    GENERAL ANESTHIA     2
27          18-06-04    SEDATION             2
27          16-07-04    LYMPHGROIN           2
27          31-08-04    GROIN                2
27          28-09-04    SEDATION             2
27          18-06-04    BIOPSY               2
663         20-04-10    DIETICS              5
663         10-02-09    SEDATION             6
663         15-03-11    EYELID               5
663         09-04-10    PHYSIOTHERAPY        5
663         20-08-09    BIOPSY               5
663         09-07-12    SEDATION             5
585         10-03-10    ANAESESIA            8
585         10-11-11    BIOPSY               8
585         08-09-13    SEDATION             8
585         12-04-08    DIETICS              8
736         02-05-09    CHEMO                9
736         09-07-14    BIOPSY               9
736         10-08-13    SEDATION             9
```

But what I actually want is where the PROCEDUREDATE is after the DOD
My output should be as below. Because I want to get the dates between the PROCEDUREDATE and DOD to determine the recurrence

ADMISSION dataframe

```
PatientID   PROCEDUREDATE   ICD             DID
27          25-09-13    SEDATION             2
27          25-09-13    LARGE BURSA          2
27          25-09-13    GENERAL ANESTHIA     2
663         20-04-10    DIETICS              5
663         15-03-11    EYELID               5
663         09-04-10    PHYSIOTHERAPY        5
663         20-08-09    BIOPSY               5
663         09-07-12    SEDATION             5
585         10-11-11    BIOPSY               8
585         08-09-13    SEDATION             8
585         12-04-08    DIETICS              8
736         09-07-14    BIOPSY               9
736         10-08-13    SEDATION             9
```

Comment: Hi there, could you edit your code so it is reproducible? That way it is much easier to help you! See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you sure that your `else` is ever triggered? Or said differently, are you sure that `proc_date >= diag_date` is ever false?

Comment: Yes it is false in some cases. I figured out a way to solve it. I assigned a value when it is false like below      mostRecentDiagID<-"r" . And then I deleted the rows which contains r.